# How to use free y axis for different groups on the same plot with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I would like to set different y axis limit for different groups (different lines) on the **same plot**. I understand that I can use `facet_grid` to plot each line on a different plot, but I would like to plot them on the same plot for a more clear overview.

I don't care about the y axis values, only care about the trend (increase or decrease) of each line. I am also open to more proper way to visualize it!

Thanks!

[image: My current plot]

Expecting: all the lines plotted on the same plot, each with its own y axis limits.

My current code:

```
FS_Mantle %>% filter(query == Gene[i]) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=Expression, x=Treatment, group=FS_Gene)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=AM_vs_CM_Sig))
```

My datadrame

```
> head(FS_Mantle)
# A tibble: 6 × 9
  query FS_Gene       AM_vs_BM_Sig AM_vs_CM_Sig BM_vs_CM_Sig Treatment Tissue Species Expression
  <chr> <chr>         <fct>        <fct>        <fct>        <fct>     <fct>  <fct>        <dbl>
1 GS1   FS_gene_30096 Y            N            N            Ambient   Mantle FS            7.09
2 GS1   FS_gene_30096 Y            N            N            Dim       Mantle FS            7.62
3 GS1   FS_gene_30096 Y            N            N            Dark      Mantle FS            7.36
```

Comment: Use percent change on the y-axis instead of absolute value

Comment: Thanks! or should I use log-transformed data? Which one would makes more sense?

Comment: Also, I would like to use 2 line types for the 2 parts of the line: for example, dashed line from Dark to Dim, solid line from Dim to Ambient. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What is the variable name with two different colors in the plot? I guess it is another factor

Comment: Could you add your code to the question, so it could be more easier to figure out.

Comment: Yes, it the significant or not. I would like to use another 2 factors to determine the line type of the 2 parts of the line.

Comment: I want to know the name of your variable with significant and not values. Then it would be easier to provide correct code for your data

Comment: Just added to the question!